# is there a way to pass input to a tcl script invoked from another script in tcl

Tags: tcl, expect

i want to execute a tcl script (say script2), from another tcl script (script1).
I am able to do it using

```
exec expect -f script2
```

But i am not able to interact with script2.
say if the script2 is waiting for any user input, i am not able to pass it.
Is there any way to achieve this in tcl.

Answer (score 0):

To hook the user up to the inferior process, you need some redirections:

```
exec expect -f script2 <@stdin >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

Note that this greatly limits the ability of the outer script to influence the inner script, but this is predictable (you're giving that control to the user). If you're instead wanting the outer script to do the interacting, you've got to use:

```
set mypipe [open |[list expect -f script2] "r+"]
fconfigure $mypipe -buffering none
# Now you can do:
#     puts -nonewline $mypipe "abc"
#     set charResponse [read $mypipe 1]
```

However, in this case you're taking charge of *all* interactions and you've got to be careful to ensure that you don't block with both sides waiting for the other to do something. The details beyond this simple summary become very specific to the scripts in question.

Comment: I tried the following code as i wanted to give the control to user. "exec expect -f script2 <@stdin >@stdout 2>@stderr" .. script2 has the following code.. puts [info script]; set name [gets stdin]; puts "name $name" ... but when i execute this script using exec, its not getting the input from me..  This is the output i got.. exec expect -f script2 <@stdin >@stdout 2>@stderr
script2
name

Comment: If i use tclsh instead of expect, i am able to pass the input to script2. This is what i tried.. exec tclsh script2 <@stdin >@stdout .. But i want to execute my script with expect.. is there any way to do this..

Comment: The issue was with the expect version i used. There is a bug in 5.43 version where gets stdin will always return EOF instead of waiting for user input.